# Auto calculator when fill two number

Tags: jquery

I have 3 different fields:

- Field 1: fill date of birth
- Field 2: fill date of death
- Field 3: age

After, I fill full field 1 and 2, I want to calculate age follow date of death and date of birth and auto filled field 3. Example:

- Field 1: i fill : 2003/02/26
- Field 2: i fill : 2019/06/20
- Field 3: auto fill : 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sample code though inputs are not validated, it is just for your understanding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Date Difference</title>

</head>
<body>
<label>Start Date</label>
<input type="text" id="start" onkeyup=calculateYears()>

<label>End Date</label>
<input type="text" id="end" onkeyup=calculateYears()>

<label>Years</label>
<input type="text" id="years" onkeyup=calculateYears()>

<script>
function calculateYears(){
    //convert start and end inputs into date object
    var start = new Date(document.getElementById('start').value);
    var end = new Date(document.getElementById('end').value);

    //calculate difference in milliseconds
    var diff = new Date(end - start);

    // convert milliseconds into years. I hope that part is not to be taught to you.

    var years = diff/1000/60/60/24/365;

    //set value of years input box
    document.getElementById('years').value = Math.round(years);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// In HTML

<input type="text" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth"/>

<input type="text" id="date_of_death" name="date_of_death"/>

<input type="text" id="age" name="age" readonly/>


// IN JS
function calculateAge(){
    // Retrieve the value of date of birth
    var date_of_birth = $("#date_of_birth").val();
    // Retrieve the value of date of death
    var date_of_death = $("#date_of_death").val();

    // Calculate the age of alive
    var age = date_of_death - death_of_birth;

    // Display the value of age in the age input field
    $("#age").val(age)
}

// change only when date of death is change
$("#date_of_death").on('change', calculateAge);
```